# How to count only a period in C?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, counting

I need to count only the periods (.) from a string. To do that, I'm using the `ispunct` function from the `ctype.h` library. I don't want to count the comas (,) and neither the exclamation marks (!).

How can I count *only* a period?

As I'm using the `ispunct` function from the ctype library, my program counts me periods (.), comas (,) and exclamation marks.

Comment: Er, `foo == '.'`?

Comment: Instead of `ispunct(c)`, what's wrong with `c == '.'`?

Comment: `ispunct`: _"Checks if the given character is a punctuation character as classified by the current C locale. The default C locale classifies the characters `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`\``{|}~` as punctuation."_

Comment: "To do that, I'm using the ispunct function from the ctype library." - **Why**? In your own words, what do you think the `ispunct` function is for, and what do you think it does? How did you decide to try to use it? if the question is simply how to check whether a character is a period, did you consider using `==`? If not, why not? I'm having difficulty understanding why there is a question here, or what the question really is.

Comment: Also, understanding you are new to the site, going forward, you will need to provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as part of each question. See [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

If `ispunct` doesn't do what you need it to do, don't use it. Just check for equality with `'.'`.

```
size_t count_periods(const char *s) {
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (s[i] == '.') count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Write your own `isdot`:

```
int isdot(char c) {
    return c == '.';
}
```

Comment: Note that functions like `ispunct`, `isdigit`, etc. take the character as an `int`: `int ispunct(int ch) { ... }`

Comment: Presumably to account for `EOF`, but I don't think that'd matter here.

Comment: If you had a function that takes a function pointer to one of the library functions and supplied this one instead, using the same signature would avoid a warning.

Comment: Sure. OP would presumably fix that at that point if they needed to.

Comment: @Chris always worth noting with the `ctype.h` macros the parameter, even though it is typed as `int` "*must have the value of an* `unsigned char` *or* `EOF`"

Answer (score -1):

There is standard C function `strchr` declared in header `<string.h>` that can be used in that case.

You can write a separate function that counts a specified character in a string as for example

```
#include <string.h>

size_t count_char( const char *s, char c )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; ( s = strchr( s, c ) ) != NULL; ++s )
    {
        ++n;
    }

    return n;
}
```

and the function can be called like for example

```
size_t n = count_char( "First statement. Second statement.", '.' );

printf( "There are %zu periods.\n", n );
```

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t count_char( const char *s, char c )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for (; ( s = strchr( s, c ) ) != NULL; ++s)
    {
        ++n;
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = count_char( "First statement. Second statement.", '.' );

    printf( "There are %zu periods.\n", n );
}
```

The program output is

```
There are 2 periods.
```

Using the function you can count any character in a string.